# bash if string starts with character

Tags: bash, if-statement

This is very basic but eluding me. I have an array. I am checking each element of this array to see if it starts with given character. I think it what i have written is right but not getting desired response.

My code

```
arr=("etpass-foo" "etpass-bar" "pass-foo" "pass-abc" "etpass-abc")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
     if [[ $i == et* ]]; then
          printf "$i"
     fi
done
```

I get below output

```
etpass-foo
etpass-bar
pass-foo
pass-abc
etpass-abc
```

What is expect is

```
etpass-foo
etpass-bar
etpass-abc
```

I have also tried below if conditions

```
1. if [[ $i == et* ]]; then
2. if [[ "$i" == "et"* ]]; then
3. if [[ "$i" == "et*" ]]; then
```

Please let me know where i am wrong?

Comment: You sure you're picking up bash? Which version ? Using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell your code works as expected...

Comment: This test also works as expected for me (although the `printf` doesn't, because it doesn't print a newline at the end of the string; you probably want `printf '%s\n' "$i"` or just `echo "$i"`).

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very good duplicate, since it's about checking a string prefix in Python, not bash (although the question does mention how to do it in bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use bashregex instead, like this:

```
...
if [[ $i =~ ^et.* ]]; then
    echo "$i"
fi
...
```

Comment: Nice approach of using regex but make sure to anchor the regex with `^` as `^et.*`, otherwise it will match `meet` as well.